# Unknown gap between bottom of img and parent divs border

Tags: html, css, border

I have the CSS and HTML below. I try changing the size of the image and it does not work. Why is there a gap underneath my image?

```css
#photo {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="photo">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/210X180" alt="Picture" style="width:210px;height:180px" />
</div>
```

Comment: Have you provided the correct html?. how come your starting the with closing div tag?.

Comment: assuming that you accidentally added a closing tag first, i entered   the code in the jsfiddle, and the width and height are changing fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ahs9dv0L/

Comment: er, wait.. what's up with the gap at the bottom of the box?  http://jsfiddle.net/ahs9dv0L/1/   And no that's not part of the image... I tried four different ones, all get the same gap at the bottom.

Comment: Bit late, but this is a duplicate of [Why an image inside a div has an extra space below the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="photo">
         <img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/1xpert/1xpert1101/1xpert110100083/8712640-rainbow-cubes-3d-render-image.jpg" alt="Picture" style="width:250px;height:180px"/>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 #photo {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        border: 3px solid black;
        line-height: 0;
    }
```

The addition of the line-height: 0; forces the image to line up correctly within the div container, precluding the empty space at the bottom of the image...  ref: http://jsfiddle.net/ahs9dv0L/3/    see also: [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: Thank you! I am glad there is a way to do it with CSS, I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try remove css border

```
border: 3px solid black;
```

And add border inside image tag

```
<img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/1xpert/1xpert1101/1xpert110100083/8712640-rainbow-cubes-3d-render-image.jpg" alt="Picture" border="3">
```

Or remove the `id="photo"` from `<div>` and add inside `<img tag>`

```
<img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/1xpert/1xpert1101/1xpert110100083/8712640-rainbow-cubes-3d-render-image.jpg" alt="Picture" id="photo">
```

Comment: Except this doesn't really get rid of the extra space at the bottom of the div, just keeps you from seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why this is happening.

Just as kind of a side "answer," though, for whatever it's worth: if you don't need the div, this problem goes away if you get rid of it and put the

```
id="photo"
```

directly on the image.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you are targeting the whole `div` section. To work on the image use the following code in your css file:

```
    #photo img {
               position: absolute;
               margin-left: 15px;
               margin-top: 15px;
               border: 3px solid black;
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me as there are elements side by side what works is `display:flex` on the parent element in this case `#photo` I've added a border red on the parent to make the gap clearer, see with and without `display:flex`

[image]

[image]